# Facebook comments overflow onto my posts, how can I have 4 latest posts show only

Tags: html, css, facebook, widget

I've linked comments to my website from Facebook and I have everything set up, but I only want 4 latest posts to show up .. at the moment I'm able to write however many and it's overflowing to my other posts. http://sportsstep.com/Live.html - at the bottom.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sportsstep" data-width="1076" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

PAGE HTML:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '311550145708699',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=311550145708699&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS/HTML in the question itself. Else this question has no value for other users. Also people that wish to answer it have to do a lot of extra work so you're less likely that someone will answer it.

Comment: This is the HTML portion:   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sportsstep" data-width="1076" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>